# Upgrading firebase-crash caused error building apk

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.3

I originally added firebase crash reporting using [Android firebase assistant](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/firebase.html) in android studio. Which added `firebase-crash:10.0.1`. Now i am want access some methods added in later version so i upgraded it to  to `firebase-crash:11.2.0`.

> This is where the problem starts

I used this [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add_the_sdk) to make changes in my `gradle.build (Module:app)`

- Changed `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.1'` to compile `'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.2.0'`

At this point gradle sync failed. To resolve this i modified `build.gradle (Project)` with

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        //Added this code
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}
```

Gradle build sync completed succesfully. Now i tried building debug apk and i received this error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzbvb;

To fix this issue i modified `buil.gradle(Modeule:app)`

```
 defaultConfig{
        ///...
        multiDexEnabled true
        ///...
    }
```

And now i am able to generate debug-build apk. But generating signed apk gives following error with 1588 warnings & 1 error.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
>   Job failed, see logs for details

**This is where i am stuck**. I am not able to resolve this issue. I tried several methods including `clean/rebuild` and `invalidate cache & restart`. Also tried adding `-ignorewarning` `-dontwarn` `-keep class { public private}` none of them seems to work.

[Error in console on generating signed apk](https://pastebin.com/Vvrth49a)

[build.gradle(Project)](https://pastebin.com/Ms6zNsck)

[build.gradle(Module:app)](https://pastebin.com/jvCakRb3)

**Update**

Adding this line compile `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.0` in `build.gradle (Module:app)` does build signed apk successfully. But shows following warnings.

[image]

[image]

I am confused

Answer (score 0):

Using the Firebase version **11.2.0** (that has a dependency with Google play services v.11.2.0), you should use also the **support libraries v26**.

In your case:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.1'
```

Also you have to use:

```
compileSdkVersion 26
```

More [info here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/08/some-updates-to-apps-using-google-play.html).

Comment: Still same issue.

Comment: Do you have some jars in the libs folder?

Comment: No. I don't have any jars in libs folder.